# Multiple (Sequential) XmlReader instances on same stream

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

My question should be relatively straight forward:

Is it (In any way) possible to create multiple XmlReader objects for the same stream in sequence, without the first reader advancing the stream to the end once it's disposed?

Sample code (Note that the second call to ReadElement will fail because the first reader advanced the stream to the end, for whatever reason):

```
private static void DoTest()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        WriteElement("Test", stream);
        Console.WriteLine("Stream Length after first write: {0}", stream.Length);
        WriteElement("Test2", stream);
        Console.WriteLine("Stream Length after second write: {0}", stream.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(ReadElement(stream));
        Console.WriteLine("Position is now: {0}/{1}", stream.Position, stream.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(ReadElement(stream)); // Note that this will fail due to the stream position now being at the end.
    }
}

private static string ReadElement(Stream source)
{
    string result;
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(source, new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
        CloseInput = false
    }))
    {
        reader.Read();
        result = reader.Name;
        reader.Read();
    }
    return result;
}

private static void WriteElement(string name, Stream target)
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(target, new XmlWriterSettings
                                                    {
                                                        ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
                                                        WriteEndDocumentOnClose = false,
                                                        OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                                                    }))
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(name);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

If this is not possible with 'pure .Net', are there any alternative ('Light') Xml parser libraries out there that would support this behaviour?

Comment: As you've already demonstrated yourself, you could simply reset the stream back to its original position (provided your stream is seekable, of course). How do you envision doing this without seeking? You'd need to copy the stream contents into memory, and then you can create all the readers you like. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm working on an Xml Serializer, given that it may be used on Network Streams and the like, seeking is, sadly, not an option. Also, writing extra "stuff" to the stream to keep track of where each segment begins would disrupt readability.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Messy way

If you're able to save the length of each sequence you could do as following:

```
int len, i = 0; //len is the length of the interval
byte[] buffer = new byte[0xff];

while (len --> 0)
    buffer[i++] = stream.ReadByte (); //copies the interval
```

This separately copies an interval of bytes from the [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and saves it into a *buffer*. Then you'd simply jongle with the buffer by assigning it to a new [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or to a String (see [XMLCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overloads).

The problem is that the first read operation is too **GREEDY** and eats the whole interval.

### 2. Original way

[Write your one stream to suite your needs!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4754454/2627378)

Comment: The problem with that solution is that I would need to know the length of each "bit" of the xml, I'm currently working on an Xml Serializer, and the ability to read multiple objects from the same stream (Without disupting the readability of the Xml) would be preferrable, as this would allow it to be used for configurations as well.